# React props destructuring when passing to component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to use es6 shorthand when passing a props with the same name?

```
const [showNavMenu, setShowNavMenu] = useState(false)
```

So this:

```
<NavMenu showNavMenu={showNavMenu} setShowNavMenu={setShowNavMenu} />
```

Will became this:

```
<NavMenu {showNavMenu} {setShowNavMenu} />
```

Comment: Not like that, but if you put them into an object you can write `<NavMenu {...props} />`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to use an extra variable, you can do this:

```
<NavMenu {...{showNavMenu, setShowNavMenu}} />
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, should have thought of that!

Answer (score 5):

you could always use the spread operator, which is my favorite way to pass props to a component

```
propsToPassthrough = {showNavMenu, setShowNavMenu}
```

then

```
<NavMenu {...propsToPassthrough}>
```